# Right alignment issue

Tags: horizontal-alignment

While writing my thesis, I see that if a mathematical formula or equation does not fit in the current line, LaTeX automatically shifts the whole formula or the equation to the new line instead of breaking it. The same thing happens with the words also. As a result, the lines or the paragraphs of the document are not aligned on the right side. What should I do?

Comment: Words should hyphenate, if they are not, then perhaps you have not declared the language being used. Mathematics will break in some places but not inside any `{}` it's usually best to use a display environment for large math expressions. `\[ \]` or amsmath `\begin{align}`. You really need to include a _complete_ _small_ document in your question, to show the problem that you have.